# Play: IllegalArgumentException: lib/jquery/jquery.js could not be found

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using play (scala) and trying to add jquery. First added it as a dependency:

```
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7",
```

Added webjars route:

```
GET     /webjars/*file              controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

And called the script:

```
<script src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("lib/jquery/jquery.js"))"></script>
```

When I run it I get:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: lib/jquery/jquery.js could not be found. Make sure you've added the corresponding WebJar and please check for typos.]
```

I also tried this after `clean`ing.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? 
Here is the target folder btw:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebJarAssets` thing uses the files on the classpath, not the ones on the file system (in your case put there by sbt-web).  To use `WebJarAssets` do this:

```
@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.js"))
```